# How to check whether a flutter DropdownButton is currently open or closed?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I am trying to write a flutter application where I need to know whether a DropdownButton is currently opened and displaying all of the options or not.

On the official flutter github page there is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43061) where developers say that the selectedItemBuilder option should be able to carry out the functionality of the callback of the button being opened or closed, but after going to the page they [linked](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html) I simply could not figure out how to achieve the functionality. The function is not even called if I close the dropdown by pressing outside of it.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2  In this the Widget DropDownButton2 contains a function type parameter named as "onMenuStateChange". Inside this function you will receive true when you open the dropdown and false if the dropDown is getting closed. Now, you can use a boolean variable to store the state of dropdown.

Comment: Thank you. This precisely solves the issue I had. Wish this was an answer instead of a comment, I would have marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? selectedValue;
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool isDropDownOpened = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(functionCheckFocus);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.removeListener(functionCheckFocus);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void functionCheckFocus() {
    isDropDownOpened = !focusNode.hasFocus;
    print("isDropDownOpened: $isDropDownOpened");
    return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedValue,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map(
            (String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            selectedValue = value;
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work. The focus is not given when I open it, but when I select one of the options thereby closing it. The focus also remains true after closing the dropdown until I select something else.